# Why can't I use `&&a` in C?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, address-operator

```c
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int       a = 10;
  int *    sp = &a;
  int * * dp1 = &sp;
  int * * dp2 = &&a;           // NG
  int * * dp3 = &(&a);         // NG
  int * * dp4 = &((int *) &a); // NG
}
```

```
$ cc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:17: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
   int * * dp3 = &(&a);         // NG
                 ^
test.c:7:17: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
   int * * dp4 = &((int *) &a); // NG
                 ^
test.c:5:3: error: label ‘a’ used but not defined
   int * * dp2 = &&a;           // NG
   ^
```

Comment: Mainly because `&a` returns an immediate *value*. Kind of, like, `a = &123;` yields the same error. Are you interested in the how-and-where in the specification, or do you (think you) need this vaue for something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can't I use `&&a`

Because `&` gives you the address of a varibale and `&a` is not a variable.

The C 11 Draft specifies the following:

> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. [...]

To get around this "limitation" one could introduce temporary storage using a compound literal like this (assuming C99 at least):

```
int a = 42; 
int ** ppa = &((int *){&a});
```

---

As a side note referring to the error message below:

```
test.c:5:3: error: label ‘a’ used but not defined
   int * * dp2 = &&a;           // NG
   ^
```

gcc (and probably others) define an extension to the C-Standard allowing the use of the `&&` operator on a single operant if the operant identifies a label. (More on this here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)

Example:

```
void * pv = &&lbl;

goto *pv;

/* some dead code  */

lbl:;

/* living code again here */
```

Comment: Is `{&a}` an array initialization?

Comment: @JinKwon: It is the initialiser to a compound literal of type `int *`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals

Answer (score 5):

Because you can get only the address of a variable not the address of a value (given by &a) and moreover && is boolean AND as @UnWind says.

Answer (score 3):

In every statement, this part: `&a` is treated as number value (because it gets the address of the variable).

So, for the first two errors:

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

The first `&` is treated as the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator and so it expects to have a value before it. (i.e. `2 & 3`).

For the last error:

> error: label ‘a’ used but not defined

Is due to the fact that because of the two `&&` it is treating the `a` as a label (see [alk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30912077/4185106)).

The thing *you* would like to achieve (get an address of an address) is not possible, because cannot get a address of a "constant value", since `&a` is already a value, but only the address of variables.

Comment: Your comment on the last error is (at least) misleading. Please see my updated answer on this.

Comment: @alk You're right, didn't know what I was thinking actually.

Answer (score 2):

`&var` gives you the address of your variable, so i would not know what you expect `&&var` to be, the address of the address? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That's right. I expected a double pointer. An address(`&(v)`) of an address (`v = &(x)`)

Comment: An address is just a single id, which has no more address. A variable has an address, which indicates where it is saved on ram or swap or whatever.